# Outputting date on textbox (involving conversion?)

Tags: c#

I'm new to using DateTime and I'm currently working on a project that includes dates.. So I have this DateTime:

```
DateTime tempDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

but how I output it on a textBox doesn't seem to work..

```
textBox5.Text = tempDate;
```

says it's not a string.. do I need to convert the datetime into a string to output it or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you need to convert it to string. Here's a chart depending on what format you want it in https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: I also found this answer to be useful.. I don't know you can format dates according to your preference.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Convert your date to a string:

```
textBox5.Text = tempDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: I don't know that the answer would be this simple.. It works fine! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Text field expects data type of string. Your tempDate is DateTime.
Refer to this link to convert it to string first.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2